# Should I split up texture atlas?

Tags: java, optimization, libgdx

What is best for performance? to cram everything in to one texture atlas (that I then load in the main class) and then send texture regions to the Objects in their constructor, or should I have one atlas for each object?

Would you put the full-screen background in the atlas? or alone since it is so large?

Is it okay to keep several animations in one atlas? Say if I had 5 Objects, each with a 6-frame animation, should I put that in the same atlas and then send the regions in the Objects constructor?

Developing for Android/iOS using LibGdx.

Comment: Well it depends on the size of the images. There is a limit to the size of the texture you can use for your atlas. If you can fit everything onto one atlas, that would be best as far as space and loading times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general it's better to have fewer atlases to reduce batch flushes. But below a certain number of flushes per frame (I think somewhere around 30-40 for modern low end devices), you're not going to see any impact because it won't be your bottle neck on performance.

You do need to pay attention to what order you draw stuff. Consider two scenarios:

1. You have a game with two armies fighting. All the "good guys" are on Atlas 1 and all the "bad guys" are on Atlas 2. Even though you only have two texture atlases, you might end up with hundreds of batch flushes because you are skipping back and forth between atlases to get all the soldiers drawn.
2. You have a game with a lot of background scenery, 20 parallax layers worth. You make a separate texture atlas for each layer. Even though there are 20 atlases, you only have 20 batch flushes because you kept them drawn in an order where everything from the same atlas is always drawn consecutively.

If you can cram your whole game onto one 2048x2048 atlas, that's great because you don't have to worry about draw order or unloading/reloading. But if you put everything on one atlas and it can't fit everything onto a single 2048 page, it will have to stretch across multiple textures and you will have lost control over planning your draw order to reduce flushes. (2048 is supported by almost all devices and 4096 is not.) At that point, you want to break things up based on what goes together as far as draw order.

Comment: i have faced issues using 2048*2048 in mdpi and ldpi devices so i always prefer 1024*1024, But yeah a well compiled answer

Comment: Im gonna go with 2048x2048 and see what happens, since if I use 1024 I have to split up between 4 different textures

Comment: @Tenfour04 If you had say 6 regions to pass to an object from the atlas, would you pass each textureRegion, or would you pass the entire atlas and then extract the regions inside that object?

Comment: I've been using 2048 in several apps for the past four years with zero reported problems caused by that from over 100K users. But mine are live wallpapers which mdpi and ldpi probably rarely support.